# How I can insert data in SAP HANA Vora virtual table from SAP HANA Studio?

Tags: mysql, virtual, hana, vora

I have a SAP HANA Vora virtual table with a single varchar field.
I try to execute this following query into this Vora virtual table from SAP HANA Studio:

```
INSERT INTO "BPINST"."VORA_TEST_VORA_VARCHAR" values ('OPT')
```

But the following error appears:

> Could not execute 'INSERT INTO "BPINST"."VORA_TEST_VORA_VARCHAR" values ('OPT')' in 3.014 seconds . SAP DBTech JDBC: [403]: internal error: Error executing query [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB SO][HDBODBC] General error;-888 exception while processing HANA Wire: V2Net error: could not handle api call, failure reason : execution of scheduler plan failed: found error: :-1, CException, Code: 10020 : Runtime category : catch(...) has been caught. , CallStack: /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.4/services/vora-manager/package/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2runtime.so.1: v2::stacktrace(std::shared_ptr<v2::mm::CAllocator<(v2::mm::AllocBackend)0> >&)+0x1e5 /var/lib/ambari-agent/ca for query " INSERT INTO "VORA"."TEST_VORA_VARCHAR" ( "STATION_TYPE") VALUES (?)"

The following image show this case:

[image]

What could be the error?

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vora does not support INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

On Vora side you can use the APPEND command to add files to a Vora table. This will however not work from HANA side via virtual tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Frank!

Then, if I need to move data from SAP HANA table to SAP HANA Vora virtual table in SAP HANA Studio, how I can to do this movement?

Thanks for the support!

Comment: You will have to create a file in HDFS which you could then APPEND to a Vora table. This will not be possible from HANA side. You could however query a HANA table from Vora side using the HANA datasource (com.sap.spark.hana), store the result in HDFS, and then APPEND it to an existing Vora table (e.g. via spark shell).

Comment: Thank for your answer again! I have currently a csv file in HDFS that contains 43 millions of rows, but when I try to create table in SAP HANA Vora SQL Editor I have an error. I don't have this error when i try to create the same table with a csv file in HDFS with only 7 rows. The error is the following: " ttl exceeded, no response received: ttl=2m0s, task=1, nodes=[2307];caught exception during execution of abort plan : Generic runtime error.(tx_id:3807)" Do you know what the error might be?